# Can't find model related descriptor field in django

Tags: python, django

I've checked a field class in the model and it is:

```
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedManager
```

I can't find in any file this field to be declared, where it may be stored or how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you see source code of Django project, you can find it into file 
django/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py

Line 543
https://github.com/django/django/blob/514b2c989a948e3c59bda0da0c9427acf643cf5b/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L543

Comment: yes that is the source of the class, but i dont understand where are defined the field itself